# Async and Await is not working, what do I do?

Tags: mongodb, apollo-server

Hi there am trying to build a to-do app. Am currently working on authenticating users using mutation. However when I ran the code on the apollo server it's showing me this error message:

```
"TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'collection')",
"at Object.signUp (file:///Users/natashachitra/Desktop/mobile_fp/src/index.js:87:31)"
```

am not sure what i'm doing wrong.

my index.js is as below\

```
import { ApolloServer } from '@apollo/server';
import { startStandaloneServer } from '@apollo/server/standalone';
import bcrypt from 'bcryptjs';
import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb';
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';


dotenv.config();

const { DB_URI, DB_NAME } = process.env;





// A schema is a collection of type definitions (hence "typeDefs")
// that together define the "shape" of queries that are executed against
// your data.
const typeDefs = `#graphql
type Query{
  myTaskLists: [TaskList!]!
}

type Mutation{
  signUp(input: SignUpInput): AuthUser
  signIn(input: SignInInput): AuthUser
}

input SignUpInput{
  email: String! 
  password: String! 
  name: String!
  avatar: String
}

input SignInInput{
  email: String! 
  password: String! 
}

type AuthUser{
  user: User!
  token: String!
}
  
type User {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  email: String!
  avatar: String 
}

type TaskList{
  id: ID!
  createdAt: String!
  title: String!
  progress: Float!

  users: [User!]!
  todos: [ToDo!]!
}

type ToDo {
  id: ID!
  content: String!
  isCompleted: Boolean!

  tasklistID: ID!
  taskList: TaskList!
}
`;

// Resolvers define how to fetch the types defined in your schema.
// This resolver retrieves books from the "books" array above.
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    myTaskLists: () => []
  },
  Mutation: {
    signUp: async (_, { input }, { db }) => {
      const hashedPassword = bcrypt.hashSync(input.password);
      const user = {
      ... input,
      password: hashedPassword,
      }
      //save to database
      const result = await db.collection('Users').insert(user);
      console.log(result);
    },

    signIn: () => {

    },
  }
};


const start = async () => {
  const client = new MongoClient(DB_URI, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true});
  await client.connect();
  const db = client.db(DB_NAME);

  const context = {
    db,
  }

  // The ApolloServer constructor requires two parameters: your schema
  // definition and your set of resolvers.
  const server = new ApolloServer({
    typeDefs,
    resolvers,
    context,
  });

  // Passing an ApolloServer instance to the `startStandaloneServer` function:
  //  1. creates an Express app
  //  2. installs your ApolloServer instance as middleware
  //  3. prepares your app to handle incoming requests
  const { url } = await startStandaloneServer(server, {
    listen: { port: 4000 },
  });

  console.log(`  Server ready at: ${url}`);
} 

start();
```

I read on the mongodb faq that it was a problem with async and await but i've put them in my code so am not really sure what's wrong.